# Search for a keyword in an array and if matches, return value from column Right to it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, lookup, nested-if

I have a sample data B3:G6 as shown. the data is categorized into Metals, Polymers, Elastomers and here I have assigned Names for each category. In column J I have several materials which belong to either of these categories of metals, polymers or elastomers. to extract the percentage of respective material, I have used the following formula in column K, which works as desired.

=IF((ISNUMBER(MATCH($J3;Metals;0))=TRUE);VLOOKUP($J3;$B:$C;2);IF((ISNUMBER(MATCH($J3;Polymers;0))=TRUE);VLOOKUP($J3;$D:$E;2);IF((ISNUMBER(MATCH($J3;Elastomers;0))=TRUE);VLOOKUP($J3;$F:$G;2);"")))

[image: Sample]

Is it possible to simplify this formula? because if my searching category increases for some reason leading to additional columns, the nested IF becomes much more longer.

Comment: Use SUMIFS with offset ranges, e.g. `=SUMIFS($C$3:$G$6,$B$3:$F$6,J3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMIFS with offset ranges:

```
=SUMIFS($C$3:$G$6,$B$3:$F$6,J3)
```